# Pycharm settings: Print number without scientific notation

Tags: python, pycharm

I have array with bunch of large and small numbers. They all print as a scientific notation when I am working through the debugger.

Is there a way to set up the pycharm settings so it doesn't print the number as:

```
incCost
array([1.29675000e+04]),
```

But prints as:

```
incCost
array([  12967.5])
```

I am not looking to run `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` command each time I am working through debugger.

I want the settings in pycharm if it exists or other options so that it does it all the time.